# Julia DataFrames error filtering by field

Tags: julia

New to Julia here! I am trying to replicate what I read in the DataFrames [documentation](https://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/getting_started.html):

```
df = DataFrames.DataFrame(A = 1:2:1000, B = repeat(1:10, inner=50), C = 1:500)
df[df.A .> 500, :]
```

However I can't get over this error:

> LoadError: type DataFrame has no field A
>   while loading In[282], in expression starting on line 2

I am using Julia 0.5 and the DataFrames package is the 0.8.5

How do I use this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you have problem with is a syntax `df.A`. It was introduced after DataFrames.jl was migrated to support Julia 1.0, since Julia 1.0 allows for custom implementations of `getproperty` method.

The syntax `df.A` is equivalent to `df[:A]` and it works correctly under current release 0.14.1 of DataFrames.jl.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am on a wrong version, however I had to tweak my code to the following:

```
df[df[:A] .> 500, :]
```

this would filter the DataFrame by rows having A>500